# eclipse --launcher.ini switch

Tags: eclipse

We're using a shared installation of eclipse (RAD 7.0, under Citrix). We need to allow each developer to provide a local copy of eclipse.ini. The "--launcher.ini" command line switch should allow us to do this, but I haven't been able to get eclipse to recognize the local copy of eclipse.ini. The behavior I'm seeing is consistent for both RAD 7.0 and Indigo (which is faster to test).

To test this, I used a non-shared Indigo installation and created a local copy of eclipse.ini in C:\Temp and added the "-showlocation" switch as the first argument; testing this in the default ini file correctly displays the workspace path in the title bar when eclipse opens, so you know immediately if the local eclipse.ini has been processed.

The eclipse documentation shows the format of the switch as "--launcher.ini {location}". I've tried modifying the desktop shortcut with every combination I can think of: quoted vs. unquoted, full path vs. folder name only, " ", "=" and ":" to separate the argument value, and in no case did eclipse find the local copy and display the workspace name in the title bar.

Can anyone suggest why this switch apparently isn't being recognized, or provide a working example? And if you have experience passing this switch via the Citrix "/param:" argument in a Citrix desktop icon I'd REALLY appreciate seeing a working example.

Answer (score 4):

I tested it by adding the following to my eclipse.ini:

```
-name
OriginalINI
```

and then my copied eclipse.ini had:

```
-name
CopiedINI
```

[-name](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html) effects the "window" name of the splash screen, so it's shown on startup.  Starting up normally the splash screen window showed the original name.  Starting up with the below command and it showed the copied eclipse.ini name:

```
eclipse/eclipse --launcher.ini $(pwd)/eclipse.ini
```

Comment: Correct. In Windows "--launcher.ini @user.home\eclipse.ini" should work, but for some reason it does not, at least under Vista. However your unix entry game me an idea, and what did work

Comment: Let's try that comment again...

Correct, Paul. In Windows 

`--launcher.ini @user.home\eclipse.ini`

should work, but for some reason it does not, at least under Vista.

However your unix entry game me an idea, and what did work was

`--launcher.ini %USERPROFILE%\eclipse.ini`

Because Windows expands the environment variable before invoking eclipse. I'll retest this in the RAD-Citrix environment when I get to the office.

Comment: Well,it didn't work. It turns out the pna agent is consuming the /param argument so it isn't being passed to eclipse.exe. I gave support some suggestions on how they could detect the presence of a local INI and add the --launcher.ini argument if found.

Comment: Thank you!  I tried the setting and it worked on Windows 10 for me, using Eclipse 2019-06

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the "--launcher.ini" works on Vista only, if there are no other arguments to the launcher. E.g.

```
eclipse --launcher.ini myOther.ini (works)

eclipse -console --launcher.ini myOther.ini (doesn't work on Vista)

eclipse --launcher.ini myOther.ini -console (doesn't work on Vista)
```